# Unique attribute for 2 elements via XML Schema

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, unique

I have the next xml structure:

```
<menubar>
   <menu id="id1">
      <menuitem id="id2"/>
      <menuitem id="id3"/>
      <menuitem id="id4"/>
      <menu id="id5">
         <menuitem id="id1"/> -error because has the same id as the first menu element
         ...
         <menuitem id="id7"/>
      </menu>
   </menu id="id8">
   <menu id="id9">
      <menuitem id="id10"/>
      <menuitem id="id11"/>
   </menu>
   ...
</menubar>
```

Verbal form: 
**menubar** has * **menu**
**menu** has * **menu** and * **menuitem**

**Question**: how to specify uniquess for space of 2 elements: **menu** and **menuitem**? In other words: all menus and menuitems elements should have unique **id** attributes between itselfs and each others.

Nesting of menu and menuitem elements for menu element could be endless.

Here what I have now:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.alexblog.me"
    xmlns="http://www.alexblog.me"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="menubar" type="MenubarType">
        <xsd:unique name="uniqueIdsForMenubarElements">
            <xsd:selector xpath=".//*"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xsd:unique>   
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="menu" type="MenuType"/>

    <xsd:element name="menuitem" type="MenuitemType" nillable="true"/>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="MenubarElementsAttributeGroup">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

    <xsd:complexType name="MenuitemType">
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MenubarElementsAttributeGroup"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="MenuType">
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="menu" type="MenuType"/>
            <xsd:element name="menuitem"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MenubarElementsAttributeGroup"/>
    </xsd:complexType>  

    <xsd:complexType name="MenubarType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="menu" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

It works, but only for **menu** elements. **Menuitem** elements just ignors.

Answer (score 0):

In MenuType declaration, element's type for menuitem is omitted. Specify it and validation will work.